# How do I supply proxy authentication credentials in windows 7 or firefox 3.6?

Tags: firefox, proxy

I've configured a squid proxy which requires authentication on my home gateway. On a lan PC running windows 7 when I try to access it from Firefox I get a blank page; both chrome and internet explorer also return fairly meaningless errors). In all cases the squid log shows it is serving 407 Proxy Authentication Required. This is to be expected.

Now I'm left scratching my head trying to figure out where exactly do I provide my proxy authentication credentials. I cannot see this either in the

- Windows 7: Internet Properties -> LAN Settings -> Proxy Server
- Firefox: Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Proxy -> Settings

So where do I put this information in? From googling I get the impression I'm supposed to get a prompt at some stage, but I haven't seen one so far

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try is:

Go to Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> Security Option, and change "Network security: LAN Manager authentication level" to "LM & NTLM - Use NTLMv2 session if negotiated".

More info that I can't verify (not a Squid user) can be found in :
[Getting Squid to authenticate with kerberos and Windows 2008/2003/7/XP](https://serverfault.com/questions/66556/getting-squid-to-authenticate-with-kerberos-and-windows-2008-2003-7-xp)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone still needs a solution: I use a software called Proxifier. It forces all applications to use any proxy server you may be connected to. All you need to do is set up the proxy network details, including authentication credentials and you're good to go. So you might find a lot of applications that require an internet connection but have no option of configuring the details of this internet connection. If you're on a proxy, Proxifier will solve these problems most of the time.

Comment: This is not a free solution.