# setting proxy with username & password & proxy server?

Tags: windows, proxy, internet-explorer

IE proxy setting dialog looks like this:

[image: IE proxy settings dialog]

Through some applications (for e.g. npm) I've to set proxy details using the following pattern (using their specific api or commandline tools):

```
http://username:password@proxy.server.url.com:80
```

Does IE accept this in the same manner?

PS: this is not IE's specific proxy settings I think. We usually end up to that dialog from the control panel. So this is somewhat a system-wide setting...

Comment: Possible duplicate of the question - http://superuser.com/questions/196343/how-do-i-supply-proxy-authentication-credentials-in-windows-7-or-firefox-3-6